# How to get touchpad & scrolling fixed with Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, touchpad, hardware, 21.10, scrolling

With Ubuntu 21.10 and Kernel version "5.13.0-28-generic", the touchpad is not working. In the "Mouse & Touchpad" settings, there is no option seen for "touchpad".
Some of the old answers suggest to get kernel version 5.11, but mine is even more latest.

Are there any device drivers missing... How to get it fixed?

**Update**: From 20th Feb, it has started working on its own. Possibly my previous attempts would have paid of after few restarts. Very unpredictable!!

Comment: Try booting to kernel -27 from the GRUB menu and see if that works.

Comment: @heynnema, this is an individual Ubuntu PC with no Windows, so directly the login page appears. Also, is that a permanent solution?

Comment: I believe that the GRUB menu can be presented by hitting the SHIFT or ESC key (depending on the age of the computer) during the boot cycle, at which time an older kernel can be selected. The point of this exercise would be to eliminate the -28 kernel as the root of the current problem. No, it's not a permanent solution, but would help generate a plan in finding a permanent solution.